# If you want to use personal access tokens in github, is it true that this is only possible when you also have two-phase authentication installed?

Tags: github

If you want to use personal access tokens in github, is it true that this is only possible when you also have two-phase authentication installed?

I work on Windows and after filling in my access token in the password field (twice) when I did a `git push` to one of my repositories, the `git push` succeeded , but only after I had installed two-phase authentication before that; otherwise it didn't.

Also then I see an entry `git:http://github.com` in Windows Credentials.

Comment: Try `git push -v` and show output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it true that this is only possible when you also have two-phase authentication installed?

No.

I use PAT and haven't 2FA

Comment: Thanks. Could you briefly explain which steps you took? You also work on Windows? Also, when I do `git push` github does not ask me for the 2fa step.

Comment: @eric - Yes, I (here) work on Win-host (Win10 19043) and (some) *Nix on hosting side by another GitHub user. Steps 1) Created Organization with repo and 2 collaborators with RW-access 2) Created PATs for each user in user-settings 3) Selected https-type of access 4) When needed, entered username for user and PAT for password